# Unable to List Contents or Create Files in /var/tmp Folder from PHP Executed Bash Script

Tags: bash

[I have posted the question here as well](https://serverfault.com/q/1132805/1026963)

**Objective: I want to trigger a webhook on a private linux-machine (its a local system not connected to internet), which can delete the spool data generated by CUPS server in /var/tmp folder.**

To achieve this

**Approach1** I 1st checked the default CUPS configuration files and edited the files there. Lines like in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

```
PreserveJobFiles No
```

and in /etc/cups/cups-files.conf

```
RequestRoot /var/tmp
```

I thought changing the PreserveJob to no will automatically delete the cups spool files once the printing is finished.

Well, Approach-1 didn't worked so I tried approach-2

**Approach2:** I have a Ubuntu 22.04 machine with Apache and PHP installed. I have set up a new virtual host, "example.io," with the DocumentRoot set to /var/www/example.io/

Within this directory, I have an index.php file that successfully serves content to the web browser.

From this index.php file, I am calling a bash-script located in my home directory. The bash script contains the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, I am above the ls command"
ls /var/tmp/

echo "Hello, I am below the ls command"
touch example.txt

rm -rf /var/tmp/cn*

echo "I am below the touch command"
```

The bash script is being executed, and I can see the output on the web browser for the echo statements. However, I am unable to list the contents of the /var/tmp folder or create a file within it.

Here are the changes I have tried, but none have resolved the issue:

1. I have tried using both relative and absolute paths for ls & touch in the bash-script.
2. I added the "www-data" user to the sudoers file under the "%sudo" line.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/example/script.sh                                                        
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/tmp
```

3. I changed the permissions of the bash script to be owned by the "www-data" user.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data    6 Jun  6 08:39 script.sh
```

4. I changed the permissions of the /var/tmp folder to be accessible by the "www-data" user.

```
drwxrwxrwt  5 www-data www-data    6 Jun  6 08:39 tmp
```

5. I removed the sticky bit from the /var/tmp folder and set its permissions to 777.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data    6 Jun  6 08:39 tmp
```

I granted full permissions to the bash script and its parent directory.

When I check from the command line, I am able to list and create files in /var/tmp using www-data user like

```
root@cups-lxc-at-ct:~/instantpost# sudo -u www-data touch /var/tmp/cnijb
root@cups-lxc-at-ct:~/instantpost# sudo -u www-data ls /var/tmp
cnijb
systemd-private-329d46999f134f4a9470ce054ae837e9-apache2.service-iHoe2E
systemd-private-329d46999f134f4a9470ce054ae837e9-systemd-logind.service-lGcUhs
systemd-private-329d46999f134f4a9470ce054ae837e9-systemd-resolved.service-Rqvc7r
```

The ACL on /var/tmp is

```
root@cups-lxc-at-ct:~/instantpost# getfacl /var/tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

I checked the AppArmor:

```
sudo apparmor_status
```

I got this output

```
root@cups-machine:~# sudo apparmor_status                       
apparmor module is loaded.
11 profiles are loaded.
11 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 profiles are in kill mode.
0 profiles are in unconfined mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
0 processes are in mixed mode.
0 processes are in kill mode.
```

**=> Interestingly, I have tested the same method with a different folder eg: /usr, /usr/example, /tmp/example, /home/example, etc..., and it worked successfully.**

**I am struggling to understand why I am encountering this issue specifically with the default /var/tmp folder. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: is `/var` or `/var/tmp`part of the root filesystem or is `/var` or `/var/tmp` an own mount? Check mount options.

Comment: Besides this, your bash script opens some security problems. You use a wildcard without correct quoting for files which can be written by any user.

Comment: Yes, /var/tmp is part of the filesystem

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).